# Spring testing DB rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am #new to spring and faced some problem while running some tests. I have a few test-classes with the following code which should rollback my (in memory h2) database:

```
    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager txm;

    TransactionStatus txstatus;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setupDB() {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        txstatus = txm.getTransaction(def);
        assumeTrue(txstatus.isNewTransaction());
        txstatus.setRollbackOnly();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void rollback() {
        txm.rollback(txstatus);
    }
```

My problem is, that if one test class has finished, I get a JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException (Unique index or primary key violation:..), because my Database is not rollbacked accordingly and Insert statements are executed again, because the database didnt get cleared. Does anyone has a tip how to fix that? Is there a way to rollback the inserts or not to do the inserts after they have been done ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just annotate your test class with

```
@Transactional
```

and Spring will handle everything (which means each test will run in its own transaction which will be rolled back after).

You can also use

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

but this is heavy because the whole Spring context must be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the `DirtiesContext` annotation. This annotation has several options. You can use the below line in your test class:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
```

The context will be removed and recreated before the test class execution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Somehow that does not change anything...